# Using SAP Netweaver to request RMTSAMPLEFLIGHT entries by cityFrom cityTo

Tags: sap-gateway

I am currently using Camel with Netweaver to request information from:
https://sapes4.sapdevcenter.com/sap/opu/odata/IWFND/RMTSAMPLEFLIGHT/FlightCollection/?sap-ds-debug=true

Through Beans and the following code:

```
"FlightCollection(carrid='AA',connid='0017',fldate=datetime'2016-05-05T00:00:00')"
```

to request information from the link above.

I was wondering if there is any way of requesting information on a flights that have fromCity/toCity by the use of the same principle (Not using JavaScript)

Edit: Ok so I have figured out how to write a syntactically correct request...

```
https://sapes4.sapdevcenter.com/sap/opu/odata/IWFND/RMTSAMPLEFLIGHT/GetAvailableFlights?cityfrom='berlin'&cityto='FRANKFURT'&fromdate=datetime'2015-10-31T01%3A00%3A00'&todate=datetime'2015-0-31T11%3A00%3A00'
```

BUT, I don't get any data back. Any tips?

Comment: Are you sure that MS Dynamics Nav(ision) have something to do with this question?

Comment: Nope it does not. Sorry I wanted to write netweaver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, figured it out...

Both cityfrom and cityto must be upper case.

```
https://sapes4.sapdevcenter.com/sap/opu/odata/IWFND/RMTSAMPLEFLIGHT/GetAvailableFlights?cityfrom=%27NEW%20YORK%27&cityto=%27SAN%20FRANCISCO%27&fromdate=datetime%272015-01-31T01%3A00%3A00%27&todate=datetime%272015-12-31T11%3A00%3A00%27
```

despite the fact that

```
https://sapes4.sapdevcenter.com/sap/opu/odata/IWFND/RMTSAMPLEFLIGHT/FlightCollection/?sap-ds-debug=true
```

shows cityfrom in lower, and cityto in upper case (As well as some guides).